# GPS time not stopping

Tags: android

I am using GoogleApiClient. I want to stop the GPS when the StopGps button is clicked. My GPS stops but in Battery Usage, the GPS time never stops -  it keeps increasing.

[image: Battery Usage screenshot]

The GPS time never stops, even though I used this code in the button function:

```
if(mGoogleApiClient!=null) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
             mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
         }
}


protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

Comment: Post the code of stopLoationUpdates.  That's your function, not an API call, so we have no idea if its implemented correctly.

Comment: If the GPS stops, It might be a ROM error, what is your device to test it ? (can't recognize it)